# Is there is a reason for data-cables shredding?

Tags: physical

Just to make sure, is there is a reason for shredding any type of data cables?
Is it OK to throw them away just as they are?

Thanks.

Comment: I would shred fiber data cables before tossing them out. Not because of the data, but fiber cables are fragile, someone could try to reuse your cables, get a faulty cable causing failed connections, and spend hours troubleshooting servers and switches.

Comment: "Not because of the data" - Did you mean that it is impossible for the data to be retained in any way, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, is impossible by any means to recover data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can throw away data cables without any concern for data having traversed them being recoverable.  The copper in them might be mildly valuable, but not so much that I'd hesitate to throw one out.

Comment: If you have hundreds of pounds of copper cable, look into recycling it.